# C# - Win Form stopping Timer tick

Tags: c#, timer, countdowntimer

This is my implementation of a Win Form app that has a countdown timer:

```
readonly DateTime myThreshold;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myThreshold = Utils.GetDate();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000; //1 second
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    timer.Start();

    //Threshold check - this only fires once insted of each second
    if (DateTime.Now.CompareTo(myThreshold) > 0)
    {
        // STOP THE TIMER
        timer.Stop();
    }
    else
    {
        //do other stuff
    }
}

void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan timeSpan = myThreshold.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
    this.labelTimer.Text = timeSpan.ToString("d' Countdown - 'hh':'mm':'ss''");
}
```

The wanted behavior is to **stop** the timer and the **tick** function when the threshold is reached.

This now does not happens because the check is only executed once since it is placed in the Form1 initialization.

Does exist a way to add this check in a way to immediately stop the Timer once a condition has been meet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define `timer` as a class field (so it can be accessed from all methods in the class), then we can just add the check to the `Tick` event itself, and stop the timer from there:

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();

void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Stop the timer if we've reached the threshold
    if (DateTime.Now > myThreshold) timer.Stop();

    TimeSpan timeSpan = myThreshold.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
    this.labelTimer.Text = timeSpan.ToString("d' Countdown - 'hh':'mm':'ss''");
}
```

Comment: Yes now it works, but we need to mention that the variable timer must be put outside the Form1() in order to be referened inside the tick function.